# Double Hash function resulting in infinite loop

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm working on a data structures assignment and my attempt to increment a double hash function is stuck in an infinite loop.

My book defines a strategy to double hash as

> h′(k) = q−(k mod q), for some prime number q < N. Also, N
>   should be a prime.

I've identified that the double hash increment is causing the issue, as switching to linear probing runs fine.

```
private int findSlot(int h, K k) {
    totalProbes = 0;
    int avail = -1;                               // no slot available (thus far)
    int j = h;                                    // index while scanning table
    do {
        totalProbes++;
        if (totalProbes > maxProbes) maxProbes = totalProbes;
        if (isAvailable(j)) {                       // may be either empty or defunct
            if (avail == -1) avail = j;               // this is the first available slot!
            if (table[j] == null) {
                break;
            }                                           // if empty, search fails immediately
        } else if (table[j].getKey().equals(k))
            return j;                                 // successful match
       //j = (j + 1) % capacity;                       // keep looking (cyclically)
        j = hashTwo(k); //increment using double hash
    } while (j != h);                             // stop if we return to the start
    return -(avail + 1);                          // search has failed
}

private int hashTwo(K key) {
    String keyString = key.toString(); //convert generic -> string -> int
    int keyInt = Integer.parseInt(keyString);
    return 7 - (keyInt % 7);
}
```

There is some ugliness with the hash 2 function - namely converting from a generic to an integer, but besides that it follows the same instructions as the book.

Comment: It should be `j += hashTwo(k);` at the moment `j` remains unchanged with each iteration (after the first probe). There's no need to recompute the probe (double hash) with each loop either; calculate once before iteration. Additionally, have you checked whether your double hash function may cause you to increment by 0?

Comment: @d.j.brown. That solved the loop but now I find out It's producing out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: What value is your hashTwo method returning, and what is the value of `j`? It may be that you need to calculate the remainder after division by capacity (as you did with linear probing) or your hashTwo method may be returning negative values. In which case you could use `Math.abs(value)`, but be aware of the special case if the value is equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, as `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: They seem to be returning all positive values, however they appear to be repeating. One sample run returned these results
`1 2 7 1 2 2 1 3 5`

I understand that the whole point of using prime numbers is to avoid collisions in the first place which is really off putting here.

Comment: Well, the chances of repeated values when the entire range of you double hash function is 0 .. 7 inclusive is pretty high. Use a larger prime to increase the range of results.

Answer (score 0):

1.error in your code: it has to be "j = hashTwo(j)"

2.error in the formula: for k=q 0> h′(k) = q−(k mod q) = q-0=q=k
 (you better look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing for a valid formula)

3. Instead of "Integer.parseInt" you should start iteration with

   private  int findSlot(K k, int size) {
       return findSlot(hashTwo(k.hashCode()), size);
   }

   private int findSlot(int h, int size) {...}